# What is a union of n-manifolds?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, manifolds

For example, a cross is not a manifold; however, it can be expressed as the union of four 1-manifolds. In my opinion, this is somehow more "tractable" than other non-manifold objects like the union of a line and a region. I am particularly interested in the union of manifolds of the same dimensions.

My questions are:

1. What are their name?
2. What are some properties of this kind of objects? Are they considered similar to manifolds?

Your answer doesn't have to be complete in any sense. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I would assume you meant unions of finitely many manifolds. Otherwise every topological space is a union of $0$-manifolds. Namely, the singletons.

Comment: @RobertThingum Yes you are right! But not every object is a union of 1-manifold or 2-manifold. Different n means different properties.

Comment: I've never heard of such an object, although the idea reminds me of simplicial/CW complexes.

Comment: These finite unions of submanifolds are carefully studied in algebraic geometry and in complex holomorphic geometry , provided the submanifolds you start with are algebraic or holomorphic.  The cross you mention, for example, is an algebraic variety and has the simplest possible singularity that an algebraic variety can have. (A singularity is what prevents a variety from being a manifold)